# 'System.StackOverflowException' Ao executar migration com DbMigrator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho minha Migration que possui um número próximo a 6500 registros como este:

```
  db.MinhaLista.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Codigo, (new MeuModel { Codigo = "ABC1234", Nome = "Teste "}));
```

Entretanto ao executar a minha migrations da seguinte forma:

```
 var migration = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
 migration.Update();
```

Ocasiona o seguinte exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred
//Descrição:
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

O que atualmente já testei e verifiquei foi:

1. Dentro todos os registros não há nenhum model com a propriedade
   Codigo repetida
2. Tentei utilizar db.SaveChanges() entre um número X em X registros (de 1000 a 1000)

[Edit]
A chamada desse migrator é usando o SetInitializer

```
 static DbContext()
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new CustomAndMigrationDatabase<DbContext, Configuration>());
    }
```

Aonde a classe `CustomAndMigrationDatabase` recebe o DbContext e o Configuration, assim realizando a instancia do DbMigrator da seguinte forma:

```
 var migration = new DbMigrator(new TMigrationsConfiguration());
 if (migration.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
 {
   migration.Update();
 }
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o construtor do contexto também. Possivelmente o problema é lá.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é este inicializador:

```
static DbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new CustomAndMigrationDatabase<DbContext, Configuration>());
}
```

Ao criar um novo contexto (ou seja, em toda e qualquer requisição), você pede ao Entity Framework que confira a base pra ver se ela está atualizada, o que executa isto aqui:

```
var migration = new DbMigrator(new TMigrationsConfiguration());
if (migration.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
{
    migration.Update();
}
```

Só que, ao executar uma verificação de *Migration*, que são duas etapas (atualização e *Seed*), na segunda etapa (*Seed*), você tem isto em algum lugar:

```
var db = new DbContext();
```

Que chama novamente o construtor, que chama novamente a *Migration*, e assim por diante.

No seu lugar, abandonaria este `Migrator` por enquanto.